# Button click to call a function that run sync hash/runspace to refresh a WPF Listview in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, listview, refresh, runspace

I want to refresh a listview each time a new item is added using a synchronized hashtable and runspace inside a function that is called on a button click event.

If I put the sync hash/runspace inside the button click, it works but I need to use a function as I will be using this code a lot. I've been banging my head for some time already trying to figure that out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below I commented the same code that works inside a button click.

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = @'
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="ListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Margin="49,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
        <Button Name="Button" Content="AddToListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="354,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

$XamlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML 
$GUI = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($XamlReader)
$XAML.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $GUI.FindName($_.Name)}

Function AddToListView {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]$ListView, 
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)]$Text, 
        [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true)]$Color
    )

    $ListViewItem = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem
    $ListViewItem.Content = $Text
    $ListViewItem.Foreground = $Color

    $global:SyncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{GUI=$GUI;ListView = $ListView;ListViewItem = $ListViewItem})
    $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    $Runspace.Open()
    $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SyncHash", $SyncHash)
    $Worker = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        $SyncHash.GUI.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{ 
            $SyncHash.ListView.Items.Add($SyncHash.ListViewItem) }, "Normal"
        )
    })

    $Worker.Runspace = $Runspace
    $Worker.BeginInvoke()
}

<#$Button.Add_Click({
    $global:SyncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{ GUI=$GUI;ListView = $ListView})
    $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    $Runspace.Open()
    $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SyncHash", $SyncHash)
    $Worker = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        $SyncHash.GUI.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{ 
            $ListViewItem = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem
            $ListViewItem.Content = "test1"
            $ListViewItem.Foreground = "green"
            $SyncHash.ListView.Items.Add($ListViewItem) }, "Normal"
        )

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

        $SyncHash.GUI.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{ 
            $ListViewItem = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem
            $ListViewItem.Content = "test2"
            $ListViewItem.Foreground = "red"
            $SyncHash.ListView.Items.Add($ListViewItem) }, "Normal"
        )

    })
    $Worker.Runspace = $Runspace
    $Worker.BeginInvoke()
})#>

$Button.Add_Click({
    AddToListView -ListView $ListView -Text "hello world!" -Color "Black"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    AddToListView -ListView $ListView -Text "hello world!" -Color "Black"
})

$GUI.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: You create a _new_ synchronized hashtable every time you handle the button click

Comment: Thanks but what about if this is inside a function on the button click event?